# how can i cal the the controller function

Tags: angularjs

I am using `ng-view` in angularjs.

```
app.controller("onedetailsCtrl", ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.url = "Samples/one.html";

}])
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/one', {
            templateUrl: 'sample/one.htm',
            controller: 'onedetailsCtrl'
        }).
        when('/two', {
            templateUrl: 'sample/two.htm',
            controller: 'deatailsController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/one'
        });
    }
]);
```

Here how can I call the controller function. I have tried below method also.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {

$compile($('#auto'))($scope);

});
})
```

Comment: Which controller method you want to call and from where?

Comment: You are using `app.controller` & `mainApp.config` , are you sure this is correct? Should it not be both the same?

Comment: it should be both the same(app.controller)

Answer (score 0):

If u include the angular js script properly , it will take care of calling the controller function. U dont have to call it manually. If everthing is properly written including the syntax , angular will directly call onedetailsCtrl since if nothing is found , u are routing to page '**/one**'.

Answer (score 0):

The controller linked to the `route` will automatically be linked upon `route` resolving. Therefor calling the linked route controller function can be invoked as following.

**Route**

```
when('/two', {
    templateUrl: 'sample/two.htm',
    controller: 'deatailsController'
}).
```

**Controller**

Add a controller `$scope`value that will be added on the view.

```
app.controller('deatailsController', function($scope) {
    alert('Hi deatailsController!');
    // add a scope value from inside the controller
    $scope.testValue = "Hello, this is the controller scope value";
}]);
```

**View**

On the HTML template `sample/two.htm` add following `{{testValue}}` to show the value binded to the `scope` object from inside the linked controller.

Comment: In one.html contains
             app.controller('onedetailsCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
             });
    In two.html contains
    
             app.controller('deatailsController', function($scope) {
                $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
             });

Comment: So what is your question? How you get controller value to the view? OR...?

Comment: Thank you for your response.my question is how to get the controller to the view.

Comment: Please see my updated answer above, showing you briefly how to add a controller binded scope variable to the view (linked with the controller)

Comment: The external sample content loaded into my layout page. But the script section in angular controller function was not hit also the values are not assigned(one.html and two.html)

Comment: Can you give me a full example of your project, please share a link through Plunkr or something simular

Comment: Please refer the below linklinkhttp://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm.Here i have used the external file for separate controller.addStudent.htm

Comment: like addStudent.html file contains  mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
         }); viewStudents.html file contains  mainApp.controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
         });